# Windows Application with different sections of an image that are clickable

Tags: c#, xaml, windows, imagemap

I have a large image, that a user can (horizontally) scroll through.  I would like to make certain sections of the image scrollable.  Can anyone point me in the direction of the best way to do this?  I am wondering if Expression Blend would be a good tool to achieve this.  Haven't found any documentation on this at all.

Additional Details:
There is one image (scrollable horizontally) of a wall which has various paintings on it.  As the user scrolls horizontally the rest of the wall containing more paintings is revealed.  I would like the user to click on each individual painting to reveal information about that painting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

UPDATE:

The Windows Application is written in C#, below is the XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="ProjectName.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:McCannWallHistory"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid  Name="gMain" Background="White">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" PointerMoved="OnPointerMoved" Name="spMain">
            <TextBlock Name="McCann" Text="McCann" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="60" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="/fonts/FuturaStd-Bold.otf#Futura Std Book" Margin="0, 40,0,0"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Name="NY" Text="McCann" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="34" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Normal" FontFamily="/fonts/Futura-Medium.ttf#FuturaStdBook" Margin="0, 0,0,15"></TextBlock>

            <StackPanel>
                <ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Disabled" Name="svMain" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled">
                    <Image Name="imgMain" Source="assets/Wall.jpg" Height="816" Width="4828.00"></Image>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Name="txt"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Below is the C# code where I make a transparent rectangle that surround a single area within the image and makes it "clickable", however as the user scrolls the area persists and the "Wrong" section is "clickable".

```
public MainPage()
        {

            this.InitializeComponent();
            //Centering the scrollViewer Horizontally
            var period = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
            Windows.System.Threading.ThreadPoolTimer.CreateTimer(async (source) =>
            {
                await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
                    var Succes = svMain.ChangeView(1615, null, null);
                });
            }, period);

            //Setting a clickable rectangle over a section of the image
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
            r.Tag = "Sample Tag Info";
            r.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            r.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            r.Clip = new RectangleGeometry();
            r.Clip.Rect = new Rect(292, 140, 365, 192);
            gMain.Children.Add(r);

        }
```

Comment: Please provide [more details](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (and ideally [some code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can see [what you've tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)) - as things are, we don't even know which [programming language](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) you're using.

Comment: That actually sounds like a neat project! If it were me I would probably separate them as objects to make a cooler presentation for the user, like enlarging the image off of the wall for a neat 2d depth effect upon selection instead of placing everything in one big image. I'd also suggest throwing those images through a good compression like [tinypng](http://tinypng.com) to reduce your file sizes as much as possible for potentially large files.

Comment: @ChrisW.  Thanks for the input.  The problem is that "paintings" on the image are set to replicate the exact position of the paintings on a physical wall.  Eventually I plan on doing exactly what you said, but right now I have to use that image.  It would take too long to "rebuild" it given that there are some 100 paintings on the wall.  (It's a big wall :))  Any idea about how to make each section in the image clickable?

Comment: If the image you're displaying is a static size than yea it's a piece of cake, so answer me that and I can show you how.

Comment: @ChrisW. it is a static size, but what I am running into is that the image is so wide it is horizontally scrollable so when I set a rectangle that is clickable it is fixed on the screen and not on the image if that makes sense?

Comment: Ya that's pretty in line with what I'd suggest, what you describe is just a DOM issue. If you want to share what you have with that I'll show you how to fix it.